# Delete images that are in one folder that are in another folder

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

I have two folders that contain images. (Say folder `1` and `2`)

The images in folder `2` are a subset of the images of in folder `1`.I want to delete the images from folder `1` that are in folder `2`. How do I do this ?

**EDIT**

The files names are exactly same in both folders

OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Please ask for any further information that is required.

Comment: Do the images still have the same title?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Loop through one of the directories with `for`, check whether the same path exists in the other directory with `if [ -f`, remove with `rm`. Which part are you stuck with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** files are pure copies with identical filenames

```
for file1 in dir1/*; do
    [[ -e "dir2/$(basename "$file1")" ]] && echo "$file1"
done
```

**Option 2:** files are pure copies with identical filenames, but modifications could have occurred after the copy.

The following checks the content too

```
for file1 in dir1/*; do
    file2="dir2/$(basename "$file1")"
    [[ -e "$file2" ]] && cmp --silent "$file1" "$file2" && echo "$file1"
done
```

**Option 3:** files are copies, but filenames could have changed.

Have a look at `fdupes` or you can do the following:

```
checksums=$(md5sum dir2/* | awk '{printf substr($1,length($1)-32+1,32) OFS}')
for file1 in dir1/*; do
    md5sum=$(md5sum "$file1"| awk '{printf substr($1,length($1)-32+1,32)}')
    [[ "$checksums" =~ $md5sum ]] && echo "$file1"
done
```

In the last example we make it a bit cumbersome because filenames with newlines or funny characters can introduce a <backslash>-character in the checksum (cfr. [md5sum prepends '\' to the checksum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424628/md5sum-prepends-to-the-checksum))

**note:** replace `echo "$file1"` with `rm "$file1"` after inspection.

Comment: The file names in the two folders are the same. I ran the first script and it listed some files names NOT ALL that were duplicate. It did not delete them in the first folder.

Comment: @TanmayBhatnagar this only lists the filenames in `dir1` that can be found in `dir2`. It will only show the files that are in common. As mentioned in the note at the bottom of the answer, you have to replace the `echo` by `rm` after inspection. If you mean that we did not find all duplicates, we would need to see a [mcve] because the way I see it, this method is fairly robust.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one of the possible ways:

1. List and sort all the file names in folders (find)
2. Compare lists to find intersection ([join](https://shapeshed.com/unix-join/#what-is-the-join-command-in-unix))
3. Remove intersection files files from folder1 (rm)

1.

```
find /path/to/folder1 -type f  -printf '%f\n'|sort
find /path/to/folder2 -type f  -printf '%f\n'|sort
```

2.

```
join  <(find /path/to/folder1 -type f  -printf '%f\n'|sort ) <(find /path/to/folder2 -type f  -printf '%f\n'|sort))
```

3.Putting 1. and 2. altogheter:

```
for f in $(join  <(find /path/to/folder1 -type f  -printf '%f\n'|sort ) <(find /path/to/folder2 -type f  -printf '%f\n'|sort))
do 
 echo removing $f
 # uncomment below once you are satisfied with the list printed
 # rm "/path/to/folder1/$f"
done
```

Comment: @KamilCuk `join` will match duplicate values.

Comment: You are generally correct. Compare is just not quite appropriate word here. In this case it does find the exactly intersection though, thus does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` with `\0` for parsing filenames with spaces or newlines.

Find all files in folder 1. Remove them from folder 2 (ignore errors).

```
dir1=1
dir2=2
find "${dir1}" -type f -printf '%f\0' | xargs -0 -i rm "${dir2}"/{} 2>/dev/null
```